# How does passing a lambda expression (or anonymous class) work in "addActionListener" and similar behaving methods?

Tags: java, function, lambda, event-handling

I've been trying to learn how to use lambda functions and it seemed to make sense but then I saw it being passing in as a function argument, specifically in the `addActionListener()` method, first they used an anonymous class and showed how it could be replaced with a lambda expression. I tried looking at the definitions of the functions in the Java Docs to understand it better but I haven't had any luck understanding how the code worked as it didn't look like anything was interacting with the object's method or lambda expression directly (Code is from the tutorial):

```
...
myButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        System.out.println("You pressed a button");
    }
});
...
```

```
myButton.addActionListener(
    (e) -> System.out.println("You pressed a button");
);
```

How do the methods within the `addActionListener` method (More specifically the `add` method in the `EventListenerList` class) get called when a button gets pressed? How does it work? Does it happen somewhere within Java itself that isn't shown on the surface?

Line 1124: https://developer.classpath.org/doc/javax/swing/AbstractButton-source.html 
Line 142: https://developer.classpath.org/doc/javax/swing/event/EventListenerList-source.html

Thanks for any help that you were able to provide.

Comment: When the Java application is notified of an event it processes that event by dispatching it to the appropriate UI component. Part of that process is invoking the appropriate methods of any appropriate registered listeners. A lot of this is likely internal code, at least it is in JavaFX (I'm not that familiar with how AWT/Swing work internally).

Comment: The lambda version is identical to the first code, but Java is doing a lot of inferring (the required class, the parameter type) from the context.  The lambda version is just shorthand (i.e. "syntactic sugar") for the non-lambda version.

Comment: @JimGarrison That part I understand but what I'm asking is how it is was being executed by Java itself if it wasn't explicitly called for in `add` method in the `EventListenerEvent` class (Since that's the method that was being used within `addActionListener`). Along those lines.

Comment: If you want to see the implementation you can always use a debugger to step through the code. A quick way to see the flow of execution when an event is processed is to call `Thread.dumpStack()` in the action listener; then you can use the stack trace to follow the code.

Comment: As an example, for a button the place where action listeners seem to be invoked is in the `javax.swing.AbstractButton#fireActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent)` method.

Answer (score 1):

In both cases, a new anonymous subclass of `ActionListener` is temporarily "created" (it is ephemeral), and a single instance object of that anonymous class is created. The anonymous class instance has one method, `actionPerformed()`.

So, in the call to `addActionListener()` you are passing a reference to that newly created anonymous class *instance*.  `addActionListener()` adds that reference to its list of event handlers and returns.

Later, when the event occurs, the framework sends an event to the `myButton` object, which looks at its list of event handlers and invokes `actionPerformed()` on each one in turn.  Your anonymous instance is one of those handlers that gets invoked.